# Standard SCPI Error codes?

Tags: usb, instrumentation, scpi

I'm writing code that sends SCPI commands to various instruments (power supplies, o'scopes, data acquisition, etc.)

The TDK Lambda power supply is returning the code "C01" which means "Illegal command or query".

Are there standard error codes or are the error codes manufacturing / instrument specific?

Comment: SCPI instruments are a snake pit of partially standard bugginess that usually breaks your system with every instrument firmware update.  (OK, maybe a little exaggerated, but there's some truth to it.)

Comment: this comment may be useless ... without knowing anything about SCPI, logic dictates that some of the error codes would have to be instrument specific ... also that, if there is an actual standard, some manufacturers deviate from the standard ... the only thing that cannot be deduced without actual information is whether some of the error codes are standard across all devices

Comment: You need to read the programmers manual. Most instruments like these have them and they're quite extensive. There should be a complete list there.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there standard error codes or are the error codes manufacturing / instrument specific?

Having worked with SCPI for over 20 years, I have never seen such a thing. Maybe "0" for "No Error" is widespread enough to be considered a standard.

Even if there were, most likely only Keysight and National Instruments would follow the standard.

Certainly a simple code like "C01" does not follow the usual practice of recent Keysight instruments to use fairly verbose messages like "137, Unterminated Query".